# Como fazer o programa reconhecer um nome com espaços junto de um float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Código:**

```
compras = {}
soma = 0
while True:
    dados = input().split()
    if dados[0] == '*':
        break
    else:
        compras[dados[0]] = float(dados[1])
while True:
    comandos = input().split()
    if comandos[0] == 'total':
        break
    if comandos[0] == 'quantidade':
        print(len(compras))
    elif comandos[0] == 'retire':
        del compras[comandos[1]]
for n in compras.values():
    soma += n
print(f'{soma:.2f}')
```

**Entrada:**

```
brinquedos 130.57
brincos 55.60
vestido de grife 1900.90
*
quantidade (retorna 3)
retire brincos (irá deletar o objeto do dicionário)
quantidade (retorna 2)
total (acaba a entrada)
```

**Saída:**

```
3
2
2031.47 (soma dos valores que ficaram no dicionário)
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer para o programa ler um nome composto e não apenas nomes únicos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao invés de

```
dados = input().split()
```

use o `rsplit`

```
dados = input().rsplit(maxsplit=1)
```

Isso fará com que a entrada do usuário seja dividida da direita pra esquerda, dividindo somente uma vez - assim, todas as palavras ficarão em `dados[0]` e o float em `dados[1]`

Da mesma forma, como seus comandos tem apenas uma palavra, use:

```
comandos = input().split(maxsplit=1)
```

Para dividir o comando do seu parametro, da esquerda para a direita.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não conhecia esse maxsplit.